# Referencing local folders into head laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

Im  including custom bootstrap folder  & css into laravel index, but none ofmy tries works, appreciate help of how to make it.

i have placed the folders in public folder of lavarel

```
<link href="css/StyleSheet_landingPage.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

[Root order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROm2m.jpg)

Comment: Remove the `..` from each of the lines. That makes the paths relative to the directory above public.

Comment: Even removing the .. no works

Comment: No, keep the `/`. Then when you try again, check the Network tab of your browser, and make sure the folder/file names are exactly as you think they are (ie the files are in /public/css/StyleSheet_landingPage.css and /public/Content/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: is exactly, but no works.. :(

Comment: If you are using blade, then take a look at asset helper function. You can simple write `{{ asset('css/StyleSheet_landingPage.css') }}`

Comment: i have updated like this but no works :  <link href="{{ asset('css/StyleSheet_landingPage.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: @harry Have you got 404 errors in console? Or any error?

Comment: no. no error, just noshow the stylee sheet propierties into the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Harven suggested in the comments, you should read up on using the [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset) helper method with Laravel.

Assuming your stylesheet lives at the following:

*Laravel/public/css/StyleSheet_landingPage.css*

Then this will work.

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/StyleSheet_landingPage.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Comment: thank you very much. and a @Harven, that posted first

Comment: My pleasure @harry ! Glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe just like here:

```
<link href="/css/StyleSheet_landingPage.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```