# Referencing images using Laravel framework

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to referencing an image I Laravel but I don't know how to adding

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/avatar/helmet/'.Auth::user()->avatar()->first()->helmet.'.png')}}">
```

Comment: What do you mean by not knowing how to add...? Add the image to the directory?

Comment: o referencing from directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing local folders into head laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404682/referencing-local-folders-into-head-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the file name with its original extension in the data base? If so, the code below should work.

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/avatar/helmet/'.Auth::user()->avatar)}}">
```

I will recommend to save the file with its original extension by adding ->getClientOriginalExtension().
It will look like this:

```
  $image = $request->file('imagename');

  if (isset($image))
  {

      $imagename = uniqid() .'-'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
      if (!file_exists('Uploads/Media/Slider'))
      {
          mkdir('Uploads/Media/Slider', 0777 , true);
      }
      $image->move('Uploads/Media/Slider',$imagename);
  }else {
      $imagename = 'slider.png';
  }
```